# В чем может быть проблема при передаче POST запроса на API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, httpclient

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "inn", inn },
        { "kpp", kpp }
    });

var response = await client.PostAsync(api, content);

using (var sr = new StringReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();

        Response.ContentType="text/xml";

        return result;
    }
```

В ответ я получаю ошибку о том, что не переданы параметры. Ссылка рабочая. В адресной страке браузера все работает по ссылке `https://site.ru/api/test.php?inn=1&kpp=1`

Comment: Если ты проверяешь через браузер, то это GET запрос, и на POST он может не работать

Comment: `using (var sr = new StringReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))` вот это очень смешно :) вы читаете строку из всех строк в строке, но ведь строка - это и есть строка. :) Вот так можно `return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это GET запрос

1. Вынесите код создания `HttpClient`, чтобы он выполнялся только один раз, а не при каждом запросе, например

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

2. Отправляйте GET

```cs
string result = await client.GetStringAsync($"{api}?inn={inn}&kpp={kpp}");
```